# What is wrong with sscanf?

Tags: c

I'm trying to scan a csv file.
Here is the code.

```
    FILE *fp;
    float pts[1000][2];
    char line[1000];
    int n = 0;
    fp = fopen("abc.csv","r");
    n = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        sscanf(line,"%f,%f",&pts[n][0],&pts[n][1]);
        n++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%f, %f\n",pts[i][0],pts[i][1]);
```

suppose abc.csv contains

```
11.654,22.332
11.654,22.332
11.654,22.332
```

When I print, I get output as,

```
11.654000, 22.332001
11.654000, 22.332001
11.654000, 22.332001
```

where is the extra .000001 is coming from?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After reading the values in `float variable`, do you want to use those float values?

Comment: @sameerkn yes, I'm actually scanning x and y coordinates of few points. So, %.3f is not exactly what I want because it may vary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to do with the scanf. It is because of the way the `float` is represented/stored in memory.

Try the following:

```
float x = 22.332;
printf("%f\n", x);
```

You will see the result is the same.

Look at: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors

Comment: Then how should I get 22.332 exactly ?!

Comment: @Apy: try `printf("%.3f, %.3f\n",pts[i][0],pts[i][1]);`

Comment: Use a arbitrary precision `decimal` library like GNU MPFR. If it is not an overkill.

Comment: Or use `double` instead of float. That won't be precise either, but tge error is a lot smaller and you won't see it with the default output precision.

Comment: @Apy To get exactly 22.332, simply do `int n = 22332; printf("%d.%d",n/1000, n%1000);`. Why do you need float numbers in the first place?

Comment: @Lundin I mentioned why I need floating numbers in the comments area of the question. And I need to scan a .csv file, not to create a floating number.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are stored in memory with standards like IEEE-754 (single or double), these standards could not represent every floating point number you expect because they're floating point. the accuracy of floating point storage isn't constant so they try to round up numbers to nearest possible number they can store.

Also the default precision of the %f in printf is 6, you can set it to 3

```
printf("%.3f, %.3f\n",pts[i][0],pts[i][1]);
```